# NSMutableArray UTF8 (Cyrillic, Chinese etc) store in NSString to email

Tags: ios, utf-8, character-encoding, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have a

```
NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

and

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

declared in the .h file.
In .m, myArray stores some (Cyrillic) Russian characters and shows up in the UITableView fine in Russian. HOwever, I want to email this, so I added

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    superArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [superArray count];
    }
```

and also this

```
NSString *emailString =[myArray description];
```

With the typical code:

```
NSString *messageBody =  emailString; 

MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
```

However, it's showing up with things like: `\U0425\U044d etc etc`

I figured since HTML is enabled I could add something like:

(EDITED HTML )

```
 NSString *htmlportionBegin =@"<!DOCTYPE html> <html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'> </head><body>";
    NSString *htmlportionEnd =@"</body></html>";
   NSString *messageBody_Pre = [htmlportionBegin stringByAppendingString:emailString];
     NSString *messageBody = [messageBody_Pre stringByAppendingString:htmlportionEnd];
```

But that doesn't change anything.

Anyone know how to get this to work so that the email composer in the app can read in the Russian characters?

Comment: Try replacing your meta tag with `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16" />`. `NSString` uses UTF-16.

Comment: Hi @cahn thank you for the suggestion! I tried this but it doesn't work, still printing \U041e etc

Comment: It looks like the cause is your use of `description` as @rmaddy suggested. I've made a test project and it displays Russian characters correctly, HTML or not. See https://github.com/kewlbear/stackoverflow-21587237/blob/master/MailCharSet/AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 0):

Never use the `description` method to generate output to be seen by the user.

Instead, build your own string from the contents of the array. One possible way would be:

```
NSString *emailString = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "]; // or use @"\n"
```

This will give you better output.

And if you state that the message body is HTML then you should have proper HTML tags in the message body including the `html` and `body` tags.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Per your suggestion I changed it from description to componentsJoinedByString, then added the html I changed above. However, it still shows as \U045 and the likes!